# grub and libfuse error

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, kernel

After I updated packages: `gnupg gpgv libgcrypt11 libtiff5`  (on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS  Linux version 3.13.0-48-generic)  and then did an `apt-get autoremove` which removed:

```
linux-headers-3.13.0-46 
linux-headers-3.13.0-46-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic
```

I got this error:

```
The link /vmlinuz.old is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link vmlinuz.old
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]
The link /initrd.img.old is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link initrd.img.old
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]
```

I searched and found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518997/how-do-i-re-run-boot-loader) by @EliahKagan

But I also get this kernel message:

```
Apr  2 21:00:45 xxx kernel: [461903.735942] grub-mount[14246]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f725626da03 sp 00007fff8793d5f0 error 4 in libfuse.so.2.9.2[7f7256256000+28000]
```

My concern is can I reboot and will everything be ok (no need to update grub) and what about this error 4 in libfuse, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "damaged link" warnings are not dangerous. They appear because you *manually* removed the older kernel version they pointed at, so now the links have no target any more. Their only purpose is to allow the system to fall back to the previous kernel version automatically if the last update failed or is not compatible. But as the linked files got deleted by your autoremove, it is right that the links got deleted.

When you run `sudo update-grub` now again, you will see that there is no warning any more.

The kernel message is unrelated and is [another question altogether](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I had a feeling the damaged link was just a warning. But that kernel segfault message bothers me. I'm wondering what that libfuse package does. Going to search again.

Comment: A guy in the chat room (hbdgaf) told me that "it's a panic when you have a corrupted partition of some kind the kernel is trying to mount something" Unfortunately I am not sure what that means for you, except that it looks like a file system problem...

Comment: @Fabby Thanks for letting me know about the check mark. I didn't run the sudo update-grub so I don't know if that part worked and I didn't solve the libfuse question.  However, the first paragraph is correct and I did reboot with no problem. So if the reboot runs the 'update grub' and fixed the libfuse, then I'm good!

Comment: You're welcome! You need the `sudo update-grub` (with a hyphen) before the reboot... (well, to make it work...  Right now would be good) Libfuse, leave another comment...